# localization does not work on remote server

Tags: php, localization

on my local machine i use localization and it work but when on a remote server, it does not.
the php extension is enabled, and i do not get any error messages.
the user have a drop down to chose a language and once he does the strings should be translated (again it works on my local machine).

this is my code:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["locale"]))
{
setcookie("locale", $configSite->  getValue('siteLang', 'language'),time()+60*60*24*30, "/");

        $locale =   $configSite->  getValue('siteLang', 'language');
}else{
         $locale = $_COOKIE["locale"]; 

}

putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");//needed on some systems
putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");//needed on some systems
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", "UTF-8");
textdomain("messages");
```

i have checked all variables and they do change once i change a language, but the string are not translated.

best regards

Comment: are you sure you can set the cookies on those remote serves?

Comment: yes the cookie is created

Comment: The obvious test you can do is hardcoding locale value. Additionally, most of the functions you use have special return values to indicate errors, but you never check.

Comment: i was folowing this tutorial:[link](http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/)

Comment: as i said, i have checked every return value and they are good.

Comment: You didn't say that. You say you had «checked all variables». It's not the same.